# how to identify IC codes?

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit

I want to buy a [LM4558N](http://www.htckorea.co.kr/Datasheet/Signal%20Conditioning/LM4558.pdf) ,which is unavailable in the local store.

I found  similar ones online but not sure if they are the same ones i need.

1)Manufacturer:     TEXAS INSTRUMENTS

Man. Part No.:  [RC4558P](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/rc4558.pdf)

2)Part No: [MC4558CN](http://datasheet.octopart.com/MC4558CN-STMicroelectronics-datasheet-36586.pdf)

FOC Code: 1467662

Manufacturer: STMICROELECTRONICS

3)Manufacturer:  TEXAS INSTRUMENTS

Man. Part No.:  [RC4558IP](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/rc4558.pdf)

Are this the same ones with different names or completely different?

Comment: Read the datasheets!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer lies in the respective datasheets. You will absolutely have to go through the datasheets carefully to identify not just the obvious differences, but sometimes subtle variations.

Broadly, the 4 ICs mentioned are functionally the same.

However, they differ in manufacturer, package, temperature ratings and so on.

- The RC4558IP is an "industrial" temperature range (–40°C to 85°C) Plastic DIP IC, the RC4558P is the 0°C to 70°C "commercial" temperature range plastic DIP version, both by Texas Instruments.
- The MC4558CN is also a "commercial" temperature range PDIP, but rated for a supply voltage of up to +/-22 Volts, compared to +/-18 Volts for the RC4558 series above.

There may be other such differences, so it is best to examine the datasheets, and take into account any differences which would affect the intended application.

Basically, "functionally identical" **does not guarantee pin-for-pin** / drop-in replacement. The actual pin-outs too need to be validated when reviewing the datasheets.

- Sometimes internal block diagrams might differ, but the pin numbering and functions will remain identical.
- In rarer cases even the pin-outs are different, and I suspect many commercial electronics designers have been burnt by this on occasion.

Comment: I had gone through the  datasheet  of each ic but each one has different internal connections and are of different Mhz ranges. But all the Ics are Named Dual opamp low noise output ics

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this qualifies as an answer, but to be sure you will have to take a look at the manufacturer data-sheet.

There should be a section named similar "Marking information" or "Part labeling" or "Package marking".

Example:
[image]
[image]

Comment: For all "how do I know *X* about *Y*?" questions, "look at the datasheet" always qualifies as an answer :)

Comment: @PhilFrost: or in other words "RTFM (read the fu**ing manual) - questions" ;)

Comment: That's Read The Friendly Manual.... no I'm not being silly..... honest....